# Reading UTF-8 data with C++ in Mac not working

Tags: c++, macos, unicode, utf-8, boost-locale

Although my C++ experience is quite reduced, I am trying to help a C++ programmer to have his library working on a Mac. At the moment, the problem seems to be only locale/encoding related.

Trying to create a minimal working example, I tested the following code, that reads a line of UTF-8 Characters, to a wide string (wstring) and then goes through the string and prints each character.

While it works perfectly on a Linux box, having all characters printed in a different line, when using a Mac box I get each **byte** printed per line (and not each character).

The code is:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    locale mylocale = gen("pt_PT.UTF-8");
    locale::global(mylocale);

    wstring userInput;
    getline(wcin, userInput);

    wcerr << "Size of string is " << userInput.length() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); ++i) {
        wcerr << userInput.at(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and my testing string is a stupid Portuguese sentence:

```
O coração é um órgão frágil.
```

I am trying with Boost_locale because somebody told me it was he way to get unicode working correctly on a Mac, but I would be happy to have a solution using only the C++ standard libraries.

**EDIT:**

The following code works on Mac. It doesn't compile on my Linux box because of the codecvt include, but I can manage that with some CPP instructions.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // setting std::local::global seems not to work (??)

    wcin.imbue(std::locale(locale(""), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
    wcerr.imbue(std::locale(locale(""), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));

    wstring userInput;
    getline(wcin, userInput);

    wcerr << "Size of string is " << userInput.length() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); ++i) {
        wcerr << userInput.at(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your Terminal has been set up correctly for `UTF-8` support?

Comment: Yep. It works perfectly with other programming languages. And in any case, file says the input is utf-8, and I am redirecting it, so...

Comment: It looks like libc++ (the standard C++ library on Mac) does not support UTF8 well. Check it by building with -stdlib=libc++ on a Linux box (you may have to install libc++ first; the default C++ library on Linux is libstdc++).

Comment: Which versions of compilers are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the fact that in UTF-8 encoding a character, also known as a *code point* is represented by one or more *code units*.

Essentially the:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); ++i)
```

loops through *code units*. You can verify that behavior by the fact that `userInput.length()` is a number greater than the number of characters in  your string.

By doing:

```
wcerr << userInput.at(i) << endl;
```

You are appending an `endl` after each *code unit* and thus separating *code units* that belong to the same *code point* which produces invalid characters.

If you instead just output:

```
wcerr << userInput << endl;
```

You will get your string intact.

If you want to output each character separately you will have to take into account multiple *code units* that belong to the same *code point* and output them separately.

**UPDATE:**

`wcin` doesn't do the conversion to *code points* by default. You need to explicitly state the encoding of the input and convert it. This is essentially what the following code does. The only major difference with your example is that I used the *C++11* standard library instead of *Boost*.

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::locale::global( std::locale( std::locale(""), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> ) );

    std::wcin.imbue( std::locale() );
    std::wcout.imbue( std::locale() );
    std::wcerr.imbue( std::locale() );

    std::wstring user_input;
    std::wcin >> user_input;

    for( int i = 0; i < user_input.length(); ++i ) {
        std::wcout << user_input[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // Converting characters to uppercase
    const std::ctype<wchar_t>& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>( std::locale() );

    for( int i = 0; i < user_input.length(); ++i ) {
        std::wcout << f.toupper(user_input[i]) << std::endl; // f.tolower() for lowercase
    }

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. To compile that you will need to pass the *C++11* standard flag.

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

Comment: Why this is not the behavior in Linux? Why is linux printing a character per line, and not a byte? Why they have different lengths in Linux or Mac?

Comment: @Alberto To answer that I'll need more time and if I have it I'll update my answer and ping you.

Comment: @Alberto Oh Wow! I just noticed that you actually solved it on your own. Oh well...

Comment: thanks any way. My main problem was understanding why the different behavior. but then... good, something is working. :)

Comment: @Alberto I updated my code to use `std::locale::global` and using the `std::locale` default constructor instead of passing the same locale / convertor. I think this is better and might fix issue with multi-threaded behavior.

Comment: @Alberto I added an example of that too.